# Change IP of RDP server for thin clients on Windows domain

Tags: windows, rdp, windows-terminal-services, thin-client

I have some HP thin clients in user-mode at a remote site set to use the wrong RDP server, how or what do I change in order to get them to use the new IP? I am remote with no smart hands onsite but could walk through if necessary. Its a Windows setup, domain, one terminal server, limited physical access.

I was certain there would be a way to update the RDP server IP centrally, via DHCP or Remote Desktop Session Host. I saw some mention of a config file but I know no location.

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your model. Like a Wyse terminal, you can deploy an .ini via FTP, and push by DHCP where to get it.

> **Network Mode (Stateless) FTP/DHCP server and profile setup**
>
> This
>   section provides basic instruction for how to configure a network
>   environment so HP Compaq t5135 Thin Clients can access the HP-format
>   global profile “global.ini” file and the user profile .ini files on an
>   FTP server, using DHCP scope options. By default, upon booting up and
>   successfully logging in at the group logon screen with a specific user
>   name (i.e., john), any HP Compaq t5135 Thin Client connected to the
>   network environment as configurated in the following sections will
>   automatically be configured with the settings captured in the
>   HP-format “global.ini” file and the settings in the user profile
>   “john.ini” file.

There is the scope option you need :

> **Configure a DHCP server**: Assign four scope-based options and set their
>   values to match the configuration of the FTP server configured in Step
>   1. For example:
>
> ● FTP Server IP Address: 161 = 10.0.0.2
>
> ● FTP Server Path: 162 = /hp
>
> ● FTP Server User Name: 184 = anonymous
>
> ● FTP Server Password: 185 = anonymous

To get the format, you need to export it from one thinclient.

> **To create a global.ini file**
>
> Start the t5135 and make the desired
>   changes through the ThinConnect Settings button.
>
> Once all of the
>   desired settings are selected, capture the settings file using the
>   ThinState 32 HP Compaq t5125/t5135 Thin Clients, build S1ST0031
>   Capture tool from within the t5135 image (see Management on page 22
>   for more information about ThinState).
>
> ThinState will capture a file
>   named profile.ini and save that file onto a USB storage device. Access
>   the USB storage device and change the name of the config.ini file to
>   global.ini. After renaming the file, place in the FTPROOT/HP folder on
>   your Microsoft Windows Server or Linux FTP server. The global.ini file
>   contains the settings that will be propagated onto all thin clients
>   connected to the FTP server.
>
> Every setting on the t5135 can be
>   configured with this file, including screen size, **application to
>   connect to (such as RDP/ICA connections)**, security, keyboard settings,
>   Altiris server information, WOL and VNC settings, etc.
>
> User
>   profile.ini files are created exactly the same way as global.ini
>   files. After capturing the config.ini using ThinState Capture, rename
>   the config.ini to the specific name for each specific user.
>
> User
>   profile.ini files are used to override specific global.ini settings or
>   add different settings for an individual user. See the following for
>   instructions for where to place the global.ini and user profile.ini
>   files.

From http://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00957439

Comment: I am in an unusual position of having any good people onsite to assist in making the original file for deployment. I have access to an HP thin client that is not from the same environment, would the ini files be compatible because they are both HPs or must they be specific to a version of thin client hardware?

Comment: If I walked into this situation not knowing if any of this was implemented, where would I look, for a FTP server?

Comment: @JustinMausolf The remote site use a site-to-site vpn ? Just direct it to a server on your side, or on a simple computer in their site, it does not matter, as if in a hurry you can use a application like filezilla server on a desktop.

Comment: @JustinMausolf For the version you can test it, export two .ini and compare. If like Wyse, only new option can happen in new model, but old option still usable.

Comment: All lan, wan, or vpn access so network is not a problem. It sounds like a t515 and some other version of HP thin client would use a reasonably similar ini file, & should be compatible, is that correct? I can create one using my version and deploy to the other environment.

Comment: @JustinMausolf This is what I would do, after you can control easily the .ini for futur server change